# Why do I find a python 3.8 feature in python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, compatibility, functools

I found the [functools.cached_property](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) in the docs, and it's marked as 'New in version 3.8'.

But I imported it in a python 3.7.5 pipenv, and my IDE finds it.

Why is that? Is it safe to use with python 3.7?

Comment: What does that mean "you're IDE finds it"? Are you sure you are using the correct version of Python?

Comment: Are you sure PyCharm correctly points to 3.7(and not 3.8) interpreter? You can open a terminal inside Pycharm and check the current Python version.